# How do I correctly install the Google Java Format plugin for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, code-formatting, google-style-guide

I want to install the [Google Java Format plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/8527-google-java-format). I have the latest 2016 community edition build (build #IC-163.11103.6, Jan 16th 2017), so version 1.2 of the plugin should be compatible. However, when I try to install it, I get an error:

> Plugin 'google-java-format' is incompatible with this version.

Looking around for a solution, I found that this error is shown if the IntelliJ version isn't supported. However, the plugin page states that build 163, which is the one I have, should be compatible.

Also, when searching for the plugin from within IntelliJ's built-in plugin repo browser, I can only find (and install) version 1.0. I guess my IntelliJ's plugin manager thinks it runs on an older build, or that the plugin actually isn't compatible with the latest build.

What is the correct method to install the latest Google Java Format plugin?

Besides that: how do I install a plugin from disk? [This help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/installing-plugin-from-disk.html) doesn't tell me whether I should install the google-java-format.zip file, or extract it and install the 2 .jar files found inside separately.

Comment: Did you use this plugin with previous versions of IntelliJ ?

Comment: @AntonDozortsev No.

Comment: What exactly version of IntelliJ you have ? Check it in *About IntelliJ IDEA* menu option.

Comment: @AntonDozortsev See edited question!

Comment: It is looks like a bug. I post the **[issue](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/issues/115)** with question on Github. **Subscribe** on this issue to stay tuned.

Comment: @AntonDozortsev The issue on GitHub can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the google-java-format plugin. An update was published on April 14th, 2017 that is compatible with 163+ builds.

Comment: I already got it recently through an update. Thanks for answering. The GitHub issue can be closed as well now.