# How to run google format by execute google-java-format Plugin in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Many questions regarding this issue can be found, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979700/how-to-configure-google-java-code-formatter-in-intellij-idea-17) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780576/how-do-i-correctly-install-the-google-java-format-plugin-for-intellij-idea). But none of them are really solves the issue that how to run the plugin to reformat java code against java google format code style

Download and import intellij-java-google-style.xml to intellij only partly solves the issue, because using the code schema will not be 100% match against code formatted with the actual google code formatter. This is very annoying when using git hook for format check when commit.

The currently intelliJ IDEA I'm using is 2018.3.4 community version

Question 1:

How can I create a hot key combination, for example: **Ctrl+Shift+J**, to run the code format? I did a similar configuration for scala code format according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980326/how-can-i-make-sure-i-applied-the-correct-code-format-in-intellij), and it works fine. The different thing is, the scala format plugin comes with a default mapping key, I changed the key combinations rather than create any.

Question 2:

Is that means any new lines will be automatically formed according to the google java code style after installed and enabled the google-java-format Plugin for intellij IDEA

Question 3:

When multiple code format plugins were installed, is that means the code format will be automatically applied to the corresponding code files? or further configuration is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**
In the keymap settings there is an entry for that called `Main Menu -> Code -> Reformat Code`. It has a default hotkey mapped to it (in my IntelliJ 2019.1 EAP for Mac).

**Question 2:**
I don't use the git hook, but I do use the google code format and it's checked in our CI pipelines and sonar etc. I sometimes use this hotkey but I've also installed the [save actions plugin](https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions) and configured it to trigger format code (cvs changed lines only) on save. This way it is automatically formatted according to googles code style upon commit and I never have any conflicts.

**Question 3:**
Depends on the plugins I suppose. I think it's best to have no more than 1 code style plugin per language / file type to avoid conflicts.